# Java: I am having some bad \n spacing issues

Tags: java, string

In my method I am simply trying to make it print out:

Sincerely,

Bob

```
public String getText() {
  letter = ("Dear " + toPerson + ":\n\n"); // Dear recipient name & blank line
  body = body.concat("\nSincerely,").concat("\n"); // sincerely & blank line
  letter = letter.concat(body + fromPerson); // adds body
  System.out.println(letter);
  return letter;
}
```

However what it prints out instead is:

Sincerely without a space under it

If I add another `\n` than for some reason it repeats sincerely twice!

My letter class:

```
public Letter(String from, String to) {
        fromPerson = from;
        toPerson = to;
    }

public void addLine(String line) {
        body = body.concat(line).concat("\n"); // body lines
    }

    public String getText() {
        letter = ("Dear " + toPerson + ":\n\n"); // Dear recipient name & blank line
        body = body.concat("\nSincerely,").concat("\n"); // sincerely & blank line
        letter = letter.concat(body + fromPerson); // adds body

        System.out.println(letter);
        return letter;
    }

}
```

And this is where its being called

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Letter myLetter = new Letter("Another Person", "Person");
        myLetter.addLine("I am sorry we must part.");
        myLetter.addLine("I wish you all the best.");
        myLetter.getText();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you mix `+` and `concat` instead of using a simple `String.format`? And you obviously need two line breaks to get an empty line. And since you haven't shown us the "repeats sincerely" version of your code, no one can help you with that.

Comment: toPerson is variable and adding a new empty line doesn't work, this is the result. https://imgur.com/a/ioC3J

Comment: This is not the result of just "adding a new empty line". You either copied that text as well or used `body` two times.

Comment: the only thing i changed was "body = body.concat("\nSincerely,").concat("\n");" to "body = body.concat("\nSincerely,").concat("\n\n");"

Comment: Why don't I believe you that? ... https://ideone.com/AL4dbS

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TuRSR the entire class

Comment: Don't post code as a picture, you can update your question instead. Also post the code where you use that `Letter` class. So, post a [mcve].

Comment: And try to run your code in another IDE or the console to avoid having issues with your environment, instead with your code.

Comment: Ok I updated the question and I am using Eclipse

Comment: How you define body and letter ?

Comment: They are just empty Strings. String letter = "", body = "";

Comment: Your code still works fine. Have your tried it outside of Eclipse?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> However what it prints out instead is:
>
> Sincerely without a space under it

Just add another `\n`

```
body = body.concat("\nSincerely,\n\n");
```

or Tom's answer

```
body = body.concat("\nSincerely,").concat("\n\n");
```

Comment: what's the problem now?

Comment: Woooooooooow body = body.concat("\nSincerely,\n\n"); fixed it but when I added .concat("\n\n"); it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Working answer doesn't worth to get a downvote too.. Anyway, I'm glad it helped.